# Select Mapped Devices with FolderBrowserDialog using Mono

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, folderbrowserdialog

Is there any way to allow FolderBrowserDialog to show up other devices or mapped drives in OSX? I Have a network mapped directory and it doesn't appear in the list.